# Writing file names used with graphicx

Tags: graphics, external-files

I'm trying to modify the command `\includegraphics{}`to write the name of the included file, including its path and extension, to a text file. What I have so far is:

```
\makeatletter
\newwrite\myfile
\immediate\openout\myfile=myfigures.txt
\let\TempCmd\Ginclude@graphics
\renewcommand{\Ginclude@graphics}[1]{\TempCmd{#1}\immediate\write\myfile{#1}}
\makeatother
```

The only problem with this is that the file extension won't get written if it's not specified. For example, if I have `mypic.eps` in a subfolder called `figures`, and I write `\includegraphics{figures/mypic}`, then `myfigures.txt` will only have `figures/mypic` written to it, when what I want is `figures/mypic.eps` to be written.

I've tried poking around in graphicx.sty and snapshot.sty to see if I can figure out how they handle file name extensions, and hack something together myself, but I haven't been able to figure it out yet. If I put `\filename@parse{#1}` in there I get nothing for `\filename@ext`.

Here's my minimal working example (just supply some image of your choice):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newwrite\myfile
\immediate\openout\myfile=myfigures.txt
\let\TempCmd\Ginclude@graphics
\renewcommand{\Ginclude@graphics}[1]{\TempCmd{#1}\immediate\write\myfile{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\includegraphics{mypic}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `graphicx` uses more code to scan with a list of possible extensions and paths. You need to replicate that code if you want the same behaviour. As it happens, I'm currently working on a package to provide such lookup and path parsing macros directly to the user. But this package isn't finished yet. The source repository lies at https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/fileparse/src if you want to have a look at it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: @MartinScharrer Would welcome thoughts on what a LaTeX3 version should provide in terms of functionality :-)

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion and sharing your code, @MartinScharrer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`graphics` is already trying various extensions and depending on the back end chosen working out which file you use, so you want to hook in there just before it calls the back end to actually include the file, not at the top level command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newwrite\myfile
\immediate\openout\myfile=myfigures.txt
\let\TempCmd\Gin@setfile
\def\Gin@setfile#1#2#3{\TempCmd{#1}{#2}{#3}\immediate\write\myfile{#3}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\includegraphics{mypic}
\end{document}
```

Produces

```
mypic.png
```